# PEP 249. paramstyle DB API v2. Зачем нужен и что обозначает?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, postgresql, pep

В [этом](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) pep используется `paramstyle`. Как он используется? Для чего нужен?

> String constant stating the type of parameter marker formatting expected by the interface. Possible values are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задает формат параметров маркера, который будет использоваться при запросах
Вот в качестве примера ([код отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184118/python-sqlite3-placeholder)):

```
import sqlite3

paramstyle = sqlite3.paramstyle

if paramstyle == 'qmark':
    ph = "?"
elif paramstyle == 'format':
    ph = "%s"
else:
    raise Exception("Unexpected paramstyle: %s" % paramstyle)

sql = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%(ph)s, %(ph)s, %(ph)s)" % { "ph" : ph }
```

Comment: Да, я это прочитал. Хотелось бы пример получить. Я не понимаю, как этим пользоваться

Comment: Это больше связано с абстракциями, так как разные БД используют разный синтаксис. Вот гляньте - [A pure Python Database Abstraction Layer](https://github.com/web2py/pydal)

Comment: Обновил ответ - пример и ссылка на ответ на англоязычном ресурсе

Comment: Что за либа такая pyDal? Выглядит как некая orm. Это надстройка над DB API с коннекторами ко многим БД?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что тот фреймворк на работает на python3

Comment: Глянул, похоже забросили... А так да, пытались ребята сделать комбайн )